# Bootstrap 4: How to align my header with my wrapper

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align my header with my 1024px wrapper. Here is the Code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wLRgyN i try to align the 300x100 to the right and the navigation to the left of each wrapperside to make it look even across the board and trying to keep it responsive.

i tried with padding, margin and float but that didnt seem to do the trick

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-top border-bottom border-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="w-50"src="https://i.imgur.com/YoN2enU.png"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="container navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">start <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">über uns</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">kontakt</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: See my post below - let me know if it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are some already defined flex classes on the elements

Try adding a Div around your logo area and give it a class of flex-mobile-nav - See css below for this class

**Add .nav-container-nav wrapping the logo and nav options - CSS updated as well**

```html
<div class="nav-container-nav"> //// Add this

<div class="flex-mobile-nav">
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="w-50"src="https://i.imgur.com/YoN2enU.png"></a>
 <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">start <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">über uns</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">kontakt</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div> //// end container
```

Also remove .mr-auto class from the .navbar-nav

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-top border-bottom border-dark">
```

and remove .container from the (navbar-collapse collapse)

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="">
```

Add to css

```css
.navbar {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.navbar-collapse {
 flex-grow:0;
}

.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
      justify-content: flex-end;
}
.flex-mobile-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-container-nav {
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex; 
}
.col {
  background:#000;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/aystarz52/pen/RzEyaE?editors=1000

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english, i meant it more like this https://imgur.com/ZkQF9XA thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `container` on your `navbar-collapse` you will not mess with the items below.

Also adding `.right` will position your navigation to the right side. I would just remove the absolute positioning on smaller screens.

```css
.border-top {
 border-top-width:5px !important;
}
.border-bottom{
 border-bottom-width:2px !important;
}
.border-dark{
 border-color:black !important;
}
.backgroundstart{
 background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/ikxZHrk.png");
}

.navbar a {
 font-size:1.1rem !important;
 font-weight:bold ;
 text-transform:uppercase !important;
 color:black !important;
}

.navbar a:hover {
 color:#347F00 !important;
}

.right {
  float:right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <title>Plauener Haarstudio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-top border-bottom border-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="w-50"src="https://i.imgur.com/YoN2enU.png"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="right navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">start <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">über uns</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">kontakt</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<div class="row wrap">
<div class="col">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/ikxZHrk.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
</div>
</div>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english, i meant it more like this https://imgur.com/ZkQF9XA thank you